# Errors while using Auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python

I've been working to make a password manager and convert .py to .exe file. A part of my code uses Google Drive's API to use OAuth for uploading files to it. The program works alright as .py file but while converting to .exe I get following WARNING messages in in output....

```
438316 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent.
438322 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package gevent.
438330 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent.
438341 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['setuptools', 'cffi']
```

This is the part of code doing all these

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
def backupsync():

    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    path = r"passwordbackup"
    for x in os.listdir(path):
        f = drive.CreateFile({'title': x})
        f.SetContentFile(os.path.join(path, x))
        f.Upload()
        f = None
```

And .exe file is showing fatal error detected.